# Disable "Reply to All" button in Outlook 2013 via Group Policy without disabling the shortcut keys

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-outlook-2013

At my organization, we've used Group Policy to disable the Reply to All button in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010. When you use the setting in the ADM files for the respective versions of Office to disable a Command bar ID, the Reply to All button is disabled, however they keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + R) is still active. This forces our users to think a bit more before using the Reply All function.

The keyboard shortcut continues to work, because there's a separate setting to disable the keyboard shortcuts. The same is true for Office 2013's GP templates, however, it does not function as expected.

When I use the Office 2013 admin templates and disable command bar ID 355 (Reply All), it disables the button as expected, however it also disables the keyboard shortcut for Reply All without actually setting it as disabled in the disable shortcut keys.

Has anyone had success disabling a command bar ID without disabling the associated shortcut keys? If so, how did you do it?

Comment: ouch that sounds like a nice Microsoft oversight in 2013 (or they figured it was in bug in last two and 'fixed' it)... just a suggestion and probably will not work but if you leave the reply all function disabled and enable the shortcut key rather than leaving as not configured does that change the behaviour at all?

Comment: Have you tried to specifically enable the keyboard shortcut through the group policy instead of the likely default setting of not being specifically enable/disabled?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to "enable" buttons or shortcuts using group policy. The only exposed function in the admin template is to disable standard functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the same question on Microsoft's TechNet forums, I received a reply from a tech at MS. This issue is fixed with a hotfix. You can find that information here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2881040.